# Visual Studio: custom project variables

Tags: visual-studio

Visual studio provides a lot of `$` variables that can be used inside the IDE such as `$(SolutionDir)`.  How can one create their own variables such as `$(MY_INCLUDES_DIR)` (that can be set by users of a project to point to their headers)?  Is it even possible?

Answer (score 21):

I know this works for VS 2010:

If you have property sheets, there is a section called "User Macros" under the "Common Properties" tree.  You can create your own $(*MyNamedVariable*) macro, and even define it in terms of other $(*SomeExistingMacro*).  If you have not played with property sheets before, look for the "Property Manager" under the view menu, and it will allow you to create and edit them.

Any project configuration that inherits the property sheet will see your macro as if VS had defined it itself, ie it will show up in the list of macros.  User of your project can just go to some base property sheet, and edit the MY_INCLUDES_DIR (to use your example) in a single place.

Hope this helps.

(How to create property sheets? See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5k4a0033.aspx. View->Other Windows->Property Manger)

Comment: This is also present in Visual Studio 2008 although the format of the files is different, and the filename extension changed in 2010 from vsprops to props. Property sheets are only available for C++ projects.

Comment: I added a UserMacro without a property file by hacking the .vcxproj file, adding a <PropertyGroup Label="UserMacros"> and an <ItemGroup>/<BuildMacro> as in a property file. Works better IMHO if you don't need to share the UserMacro between projects. If anyone knows how to do this in the GUI without hacking the .vcxproj file I'd love to hear it. (VS2017)

Answer (score 7):

I created a property style sheet, to specify which Python (and SCons), now in my vcxproj, I can include the Python include dir by adding $(PythonIncludeDir) to the additional includes property.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project ToolsVersion="4.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
    <ImportGroup Label="PropertySheets" />
    <PropertyGroup Label="UserMacros">
        <PythonDir>C:\Python27_64</PythonDir>
        <PythonExe>$(PythonDir)\python.exe</PythonExe>
        <PythonIncludeDir>$(PythonDir)\include</PythonIncludeDir>
        <PythonLibDir>$(PythonDir)\libs</PythonLibDir>
        <SCons>$(PythonExe) $(PythonDir)\Scripts\scons.py</SCons>
    </PropertyGroup>
    <ItemDefinitionGroup />
    <ItemGroup>
        <BuildMacro Include="PythonDir">
            <Value>$(PythonDir)</Value>
            <EnvironmentVariable>true</EnvironmentVariable>
        </BuildMacro>
        <BuildMacro Include="PythonExe">
            <Value>$(PythonExe)</Value>
            <EnvironmentVariable>true</EnvironmentVariable>
        </BuildMacro>
        <BuildMacro Include="PythonIncludeDir">
            <Value>$(PythonIncludeDir)</Value>
            <EnvironmentVariable>true</EnvironmentVariable>
        </BuildMacro>
        <BuildMacro Include="PythonLibDir">
            <Value>$(PythonLibDir)</Value>
            <EnvironmentVariable>true</EnvironmentVariable>
        </BuildMacro>
        <BuildMacro Include="SCons">
            <Value>$(SCons)</Value>
            <EnvironmentVariable>true</EnvironmentVariable>
        </BuildMacro>
    </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

Answer (score 5):

You can follow any solution as described below.

1. Set the environment variable in a batch file. Create a batch file and insert code like the following:

   `set MY_INCLUDES_DIR=D:\MyIncludes
   call "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\Tools\vsvars32.bat"
   "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe"  D:\MySolution.sln`

Then start the Visual Studio solution by double-clicking this file. An advantage of this approach is that all projects can use the same environment variable.

2. Define an xml tag in a Visual Studio project file within a PropertyGroup. One preexisting PropertyGroup that you can use for this purpose is the one with the label "UserMacros", which is empty by default.

```xml
<PropertyGroup Label="UserMacros">
    <!-- Add the following line. -->
    <MY_INCLUDES_DIR>D:\MyIncludes\</MY_INCLUDES_DIR>
</PropertyGroup>
```

3. Create a system environment variable named `MY_INCLUDES_DIR`.
4. Go to **View**(menubar) -> **Property Manager**.
   Select project, select platform and configuration, right click on **Microsoft.Cpp.x64.user** then go to **User Macros** Tab and click on **Add Macros**.

Whether you choose option 1, 2, 3, or 4, you can then refer to `$(MY_INCLUDES_DIR)` in your Visual Studio project files.

Answer (score 0):

Just had to do the same thing. I have three solutions which include a common project. Each of the solutions needs to build the common project with slightly different settings.

Discovered this can be easily done using Project Property Sheets. Create a Property Sheet file for the settings you want to change and save it in the solution directory. Open the Project file in a text editor (or in VS with Open With \ Source Code Text Editor) and find the directory path of the Property Sheet. Modify it so that the path used is '$(SolutionDir)'.

You now have a Visual Studio Project that loads solution specific Property Sheets.