# Get a path of my solution VS C#

Tags: visual-studio

Visual Studio provides a lot of `$` variables that can be used inside the IDE, such as `$(SolutionDir)`. How can one create their own variables such as `$(Azure)` for all projects?

Comment: it's macro project .. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c02as0cs.aspx .. now, what do you need ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Visual Studio: custom project variables](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4249844/visual-studio-custom-project-variables)