# C++ project build, but IDE shows error

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013, intellisense, glew

**`Error: cannot open source file "GL/glew.h"`**

I have the following code :

```
//Include GLEW  
#include <GL/glew.h>  

//Include GLFW  
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>  

//Include the standard C++ headers  
#include <stdio.h>  
#include <stdlib.h>  

//Define an error callback  
static void error_callback(int error, const char* description)
{
...
```

I took from there: http://www.41post.com/5178/programming/opengl-configuring-glfw-and-glew-in-visual-cplusplus-express#part4

In order to have a somewhat portable solution, before I even started Visual Studio 2013 I created two System Environment Variable in windows.

`GLEW=C:\Install\Development\C++\Framework\glew-1.10.0-win32\glew-1.10.0`
`GLFW=C:\Install\Development\C++\Framework\glfw-3.0.4.bin.WIN32\glfw-3.0.4.bin.WIN32`

So in my project I could for instance write a additional include folder as: `%GLEW%\include`

As I said, it builds fine and runs fine as well.

Yet, not having intellisense behave properly is really annoying.
How to fix it?

Comment: What...Is...The...IDE...Error?  Please **edit** your post with the information.

Comment: Right, I eventually forgot the main piece of information...

Comment: You may want to create project variables instead of environment variables, e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4249844/visual-studio-custom-project-variables

Answer (score 0):

My syntax was actually wrong, you cant use global environment variable in VS using %<name>% but you have to use $(%<name>).

Wherever I wrote `%GLEW%\include` I should have `$(GLEW)\include`.

It's working fine now.

Though I'm completely clueless why it built.

This post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11543754/910813 got me to remind that.